# Safari Browser issue in jQuery/javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issues on Safari Browser. I have a table header arranged by this:

```
Color Code, Color, Size, Total Box, Total Pairs
```

This layout is working on Chrome but when it comes to Safari its Arrangement is this:

```
Total Box Total Pairs, Size, Color Code, Color
```

Please Help. Thanks. Here is my code.

```
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
var thead = document.createElement('THEAD');
var tbody = document.createElement('TBODY');

var tr = thead.insertRow(0);
var td;

// color code header
td = tr.insertCell(tr.length);
$(td).attr('rowspan',2);
$(td).text('Code');
//color name header
td = tr.insertCell(tr.length);
$(td).attr('rowspan',2);
$(td).text('Color');
//color size header
td = tr.insertCell(tr.length);
$(td).attr('colspan',season.Size.length);
$(td).text('Size');
//color total pairs header
td = tr.insertCell(tr.length);
$(td).attr('rowspan',2);
$(td).text('Total Pairs');
//color total box header
td = tr.insertCell(tr.length);
$(td).attr('rowspan',2);
$(td).text('Total Box');
```

Comment: Does it work with `insertCell(-1)` instead of `insertCell(tr.length)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an issue in safari browser. You have an error in your code `tr.length` actually doesn't return the length, it returns `undefined`. So the order could be vary in browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/6mgu6goj/5/

**Reason**

```
tr.length
```